# How to count transactions by clientcode

Tags: r

In R am trying to count which *clientcodes* had number of transactions >400 in an auction df (each clientcode has multiple transactions labeled in columns by price, buyer, etc).

I've tried a for loop to count *clientcodes*, but I'm only getting the unique number of clients (not the clients who have made over 400 transactions).

My Dataframe (has 35k+rows), a sample:

```
year month day hour minute second shipcode clientcode kilos price  
2016     1   4   17     23     12     1350       1467  2.25 10.45        
2016     1   4   17     23     17     1350        528  2.95  6.85                 
2016     1   4   17     24     29     1080       1349  1.80  7.85
```

I've tried the following, but is not working:

```r
count <-0
> for (i in uniqueclients >400){
    count <- count +1
}
print(count)
```

Comment: Try with `table(df1$clientcode)`

Comment: Thank you - this gives me a table with the clientcodes, it doesn't sort out the ones with more than 400 transactions.

Answer (score 0):

If we need to subset the ones that have more than 400 transactions

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(clientcode) 
    filter(n() > 400)
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
subset(df1, clientcode %in% names(which(table(clientcode) > 400)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
temp <- data.frame(month = c(1,2,3,2,5,5,5), day = c(5,6,7,3,3,3,3))
sum(table(temp$month) > 2) #> 1
# only 5 has more than 2 appearances in month
```